# Using ADODB SQL in VBA, why are Strings truncated [to 255] only when I use grouping?

Tags: excel, vba, activex, ado, adodb

I’m using ADODB to query on Sheet1. If I fetch the data using SQL query on the sheet as below without grouping I’m getting all characters from comment.

However, if I use grouping my characters are truncated to 255.

Note – My first row contains 800 len of characters so drivers have identified the datatype correctly.

---

Here is my query output without grouping

```
Select  Product, Value, Comment, len(comment) from [sheet1$A1:T10000]
```

[image: without grouping]

With grouping

```
Select  Product, sum(value), Comment, len(comment) from [sheet1$A1:T10000] group by Product, Comment
```

[image: with grouping]

Comment: Can you add a column to print what type "comment" is? If you're not manually setting it, presumably it's automatically choosing the type `short text` when you `group by` in an attempt to make the computation faster

Comment: Agree, but in the first row itself i have 800 characters comment in general format so while reading the file drivers should have identified its data type. Right? [memo data type i guess, if i read the other websites correctly.] if i dont use grouping it is giving me correct length.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for posting this! During my 20+ years of database development using ADO recordsets I had never faced this issue until this week. Once I traced the truncation to the recordset I was really scratching my head. Couldn't figure how/why it was happening until I found your post and you got me focused on the GROUP BY. Sure enough, that was the cause (some kind of ADO bug I guess). I was able to work around it by putting correlated scalar sub-queries in the SELECT list, vice using JOIN and GROUP BY.

To elaborate...

At least 9 times out of 10 (in my experience) JOIN/GROUP BY syntax can be replaced with correlated scalar subquery syntax, with no appreciable loss of performance. That's fortunate in this case since there is apparently a bug with ADO recordset objects whereby GROUP BY syntax results in the truncation of text when the string length is greater than 255 characters.

The first example below uses JOIN/GROUP BY. The second uses a correlated scalar subquery. Both would/should provide the same results. However, if any comment is greater than 255 characters these 2 queries will NOT return the same results if an ADODB recordset is involved.

Note that in the second example the last column in the SELECT list is itself a full select statement. It's called a scalar subquery because it will only return 1 row / 1 column. If it returned multiple rows or columns an error would be thrown. It's also known as a correlated subquery because it references something that is immediately outside its scope (e.emp_number in this case).

```
SELECT e.emp_number, e.emp_name, e.supv_comments, SUM(i.invoice_amt) As total_sales
FROM employees e INNER JOIN invoices i ON e.emp_number = i.emp_number
GROUP BY e.emp_number, e.emp_name, e.supv_comment
```

```
SELECT e.emp_number, e.emp_name, e.supv_comments,
(SELECT SUM(i.invoice_amt) FROM invoices i WHERE i.emp_number = e.emp_number) As total_sales
FROM employees e
```